# Magento vs. WooCommerce for small shops

Tags: magento, woocommerce

I know that are a lot of threads based on this comparison but i still have some questions that are not satisfied. I read that magento uses a lot of resources and it's not appropriate for small shops. I am currently using woocommerce but i am not content with it because it lacks a lot of features for example:

- doesn't have an integrated invoicing system and i can't issues invoices from API
- most of the couriers don't have a platform for it (in my country at least)
- sometimes is very slow(i've done all the possible tweaks)
- i always have a feeling that i can't reside on it
- doesn't have reports out of the box
- others

Of course all of the above can be achieved with plugins, but it's annoying when you must control and update and take care of 20-30 plugins, also slows down the website a lot.

On the other hand, Magento seems to have all this functionalities already in place, but for what i had read, is not appropriate because:

- it's a lot more expensive
- it's harder to customize and maintain (i am a PHP dev so i may learn how to do it)
- it needs a VPS to run correctly(not sure)
- it's particularly used for big shops with 10k+ products

I am not sure all the info above is correct, is what i've found on the internet. Magento also offers another nice functionality, multiple shops inside the same platform. I need to make 1 store of about 2000 products and some stores about 5 10 products.

I especially want to be as automatized as possible, so it doesn't take a lot of time to take care of the invoices, orders etc.

I am interested in finding which options suits me better. Also i want to know if the info above is true and also i would like to hear more about which option to choose and why. The more detailed answer, the better.

Comment: Hi Alex7, thanks for the detailed post... it's always useful to have a lot of background information as that enables more specific answers. However, I couldn't quite identify your question here. Are you looking for someone to confirm what you're read about Magento online? Or are you interested in hearing more opinions for one or the other?

Comment: @FarhadD hi, thanks for the comment, i updated the question, i want to know more pros and cons and which si better for this use cases.

Answer (score 2):

As i understand, the problem you have is (mostly) of financial art:

whether you are ready to pay more for more hardware (server/CPU/RAM) to run more sophisticated and cushy software (Magento), which will save you your time resources (installing, coding and customizing of gazillions of wordpress plugins).

> it's a lot more expensive

You mean hardware resources? - yes, indeed.

> it's harder to customize and maintain (i am a PHP dev so i may learn
>   how to do it)

no, not really - its well documented and have a strong and streamlined api.

> it needs a VPS

Surely, it will not satisfy both of you and your visitors, if you try to run magento on shared hosting with no dedicated RAM ;) But [here](https://goo.gl/72QV0b) you will find some good advice, how to make magento flying like a wind ;)

> it's particularly used for big shops with 10k+ products

Some time will go by and you will want (or even must) to grow -it is better if you aren't limited by software.

Comment: one of the issue was always the financial part because i mostly develop for startups or small companies. From your experience, a website with about 5000 visits / month and 200 products will work ok on a shared hosting ? Another question will be, what plugins i would need to buy for a standard shop (excepting the template) . I would like an estimated cost of this plugins in order to form an idea. Thanks

Comment: Read this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/460/what-is-the-best-magento-server-setup, http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/kbase/magento/magento-system-requirements.html, Indeed, for 5K vistis monthly magento is too oversized.

Comment: well thanks for the links, they are really helpful. If not woocommerce or magento, what other options do i have in between? That i can run on a shared server and also comes with a lot of features built in ? thanks

Comment: Very nice answer!!

Comment: @Alex7 oh, inbetween you have Drupal with ubercard and Joomla with a real bunch of ecommerce extensions. And not to forget uncountable standalone and hosted shop software. It is very important to know to make a software decision, what kind of products you plan to sell, are there many product variations, like colors, weights, sizes etc. how looks your design of shipping and storage procedures. Different software have different strengths and week sides, like missing possibility to work with international shipping, or miss some credit card connector, or even it can everything, but is a SEO horror